# Google Drive API Folder Permission

Tags: google-drive-api

If I give a folder permission, is it possible to not cascade down that permission to subfolders?
Here is a folder structure

Folder A 
Folder A\Folder B 
Folder A\Folder C

If I give Folder A permission, I dont want to give folder B and Folder C permission.

When I insert permission to folderid, it also give anything under it that permission.

Answer (score 1):

Yes what you see is the current behavior. Once you give permission for user U to folder A you need to loop through the children folders and remove U from their permissions. Gets tricky if some children already had such permission so you need to load their permissions before changing A and compare.

Answer (score 0):

Just give A the permissions you want it to have. Then give B and C the permission you want it to have.

```
       A - Permission 1                    B - Permission 2      C - Permission 2
B | Permission 1  C | Permission 1
```

Result

```
       A Permission 1
B Permission 2 C Permission 2
```

KEY

```
- = Set the permission to
| = The permission is inherited
```

Comment: I think stackoverflow didnt retain my new line characters. Folder B and Folder C are inside folder A. If I give permission to folder A, it cascades down to folder b and folder c.

Comment: I know. Then change B and C to the permission you want them to have.