# Google Drive API: disable permission inhertitance

Tags: google-drive-api

On Google Drive every document and folder within a folder inherited the parent permissions. Is there any way to turn this off by using the google drive api?

Comment: AFAIK, their is no API method/ file property in Drive REST API that will turn of permission inheritance automatically. A workaround would be manually calling `Permissions: list` and `Permissions: delete` to compare and delete permission/s the file as stated in a SO post : [Google Drive API Folder Permission](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20230255/5995040). Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there anyway to determine if the permission is inherited or directly set?

Comment: @J.Hu Not directly, but you can remove the permission from the parent and then check if it gets removed from the child.